# Graph based on weekly data

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Colleagues programmers, good night. I'm having a hard time putting together a chart of weekly records using PHP, MySQL and the Highcharts library.

I have records of connections and disconnections, in which it is saved in the format *2017-03-30 16:43:04*, but in the graph in lines I need to display this information in a period of 7 days.

For example with the beginning of the week today: the abscissa axis would contain 7 values **03/04, 04/04, 04/04, 06/04, 07/04, 08/04 and 09/04** and the axis of the Ordinates would have integer values representing a certain amount of connection or disconnection.

I do not know how to generate this data in the backend, especially the SQL query.

Table columns:

`id | username | event | date`

Where **id** is the **event** id, **username** is a **username**, **event** can assume connection or disconnection values, and **date** is the date in *2017-03-30 16:43:04* format.

Chart example:

[image]

The ugly way I did:

Get 6 days ago + today in DD / MM format:

`$date['timestamp'] = array(
            '0' => $this->db->select("DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 6 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) AS dateX")->get()->row()->dateX,
            '1' => $this->db->select("DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 5 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) AS dateX")->get()->row()->dateX,
            '2' => $this->db->select("DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 4 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) AS dateX")->get()->row()->dateX,
            '3' => $this->db->select("DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 3 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) AS dateX")->get()->row()->dateX,
            '4' => $this->db->select("DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 2 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) AS dateX")->get()->row()->dateX,
            '5' => $this->db->select("DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) AS dateX")->get()->row()->dateX,
            '6' => $this->db->select("DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL + 0 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) AS dateX")->get()->row()->dateX
        );`

Get connection and disconnections based on the dates above:

`$date['series'] = array(
            'con' => array(
                '0' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'conexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,

                '1' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'conexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,
                '2' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'conexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,
                '3' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'conexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,
                '4' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'conexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,
                '5' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'conexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,
                '6' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'conexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 0 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX

            ),
            'dis' => array(
                '0' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'desconexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,

                '1' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'desconexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,
                '2' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'desconexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,
                '3' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'desconexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,
                '4' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'desconexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,
                '5' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'desconexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX,
                '6' => $this->db->select('COUNT(id_ConnectionLog) AS dateX')->from('connection_log')->where('cl_Event', 'desconexão')->where('cl_Client', $client_name)->where('date(cl_Date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 0 DAY')->get()->row()->dateX

            )
        );`

Comment: Something like `select count(*), week(date_column) from table group by week(date_column)`, maybe? Then you build the line graph from each data point

Comment: @chris85 I solved the problem but in an ugly way. I'll edit my question the way I did.